# ReferenceError: ueUserInfoListView is not defined

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am working on QML/Qt app and I have following `ListView`, names **ueUserInfoListView**:

```
    ListView
    {
        id: ueUserInfoListView

        antialiasing: true

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.margins: 8

        clip: true

        spacing: 64

        orientation: ListView.Horizontal

        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true

        delegate: Image
        {
            id: ueUserInfoListViewDelegate

            source: "image://uePeopleModel/"+model.ueRoleImage

            opacity: 0.3

            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            function ueDoOpacity()
            {
                if(ueUserInfoListViewDelegate===ueUserInfoListView.currentItem)
                    opacity=1.0
                else
                    opacity=0.3
            }

            Behavior on opacity
            {
                NumberAnimation
                {
                    duration: 300
                }   // NumberAnimation
            }   // Behavior

            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                ueUserInfoListViewDelegate.focusChanged.connect(ueDoOpacity)
            }   // Component.onCompleted
        }   // delegate

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            model=uePeopleModel
        }   // Component.onCompleted

        preferredHighlightBegin: width/2-70
        preferredHighlightEnd: width/2+70
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        currentIndex: count/2
    }   // ListView
```

I am tryigin to call **ueUserInfoListView** from another separated (in terms of file) `Item`, named **ueProductSelector**:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

import si.mikroelektronika 1.0

Item
{
    id: ueProductSelector

    antialiasing: true

    clip: true

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ueProductSelectorWrapper

        radius: 16
        gradient: Gradient
        {
            GradientStop
            {
                position: 0
                color: "#ffffff"
            }   // GradientStop

            GradientStop
            {
                position: 1
                color: "#000000"
            }   // GradientStop
        }   // Gradient

        border.color: "#4682b4"
        border.width: 1

        antialiasing: true

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout
        {
            anchors.margins: parent.radius/2

            spacing: 0
            antialiasing: true

            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            GridView
            {
                id: ueProductGridView

                antialiasing: true

                clip: true

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                cellWidth: 144
                cellHeight: 144

                model: ueProductsModel

                delegate: Rectangle
                {
                    radius: 16

                    clip: true

                    width: ueProductGridView.cellWidth-8
                    height: ueProductGridView.cellHeight-8

                    border.color: "#4682b4"

                    antialiasing: true

                    gradient: Gradient
                    {
                        GradientStop
                        {
                            position: 0
                            color: "#000000"

                            ParallelAnimation on color
                            {
                                id: ueProductSelectorDelegateMouseAreaAnimation

                                loops: 1
                                running: false//ueDelegateMouseArea.pressed

                                ColorAnimation
                                {
                                    from: "#4682b4"
                                    to: "#000000"
                                    duration: 100
                                }   // ColorAnimation
                            }   // ParallelAnimation
                        }   // GradientStop

                        GradientStop
                        {
                            position: 1
                            color: "#ffffff"
                        }   // GradientStop
                    }   // Gradient

                    MouseArea
                    {
                        id: ueDelegateMouseArea

                        anchors.fill: parent

                        onClicked:
                        {
                            var selectedIndex=ueProductGridView.currentIndex=index;

                            ueProductSelectorDelegateMouseAreaAnimation.running=true;
                            ueProductGridView.currentIndex=index;

                             ueOrdersModel.ueSetRecordValues(ueUserInfoListView.model.get(ueUserInfoListView.currentIndex).ueRoleId,
                                                             uePlacesListView.model.get(uePlacesListView.currentIndex).ueRoleId,
                                                             ueProductGridView.model.get(selectedIndex).ueRoleProductId,
                                                             1);
                        }   // onClicked
                    }   // MouseArea

                    ColumnLayout
                    {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        antialiasing: true

                        spacing: 8

                        Image
                        {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: false
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.AlignTop
                            Layout.topMargin: ueProductSelectorWrapper.radius+4

                            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

                            antialiasing: true
                            source: "image://ueProductsModel/"+model.ueRoleImage
                        }   // Image

                        Text
                        {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: true
                            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.AlignBottom
                            Layout.bottomMargin: ueProductSelectorWrapper.radius+4

                            color: "#000000"

                            text: model.ueRoleProductName
                            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                            font.family: "Courier"
                            textFormat: Text.RichText

                            font.bold: true
                            font.pointSize: 10

                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        }   // Text
                    }   // ColumnLayout
                }   // delegate

                Component.onCompleted:
                {
                    ueProductSelectorOpacityAnimator.running=true
                }
            }   // GridView
        }   // ColumnLayot
    }   // Rectangle
}   // Item
```

and I get following error:

> qrc:/gui/items/UeProductSelector.qml:126:   ReferenceError:
>   ueUserInfoListView is not defined
>   Why?

Comment: You're asking a question about a variable that we can't see. Where is it defined? What file is the `MouseArea` in? What file is `ueUserInfoListView` in? I think you need to ask yourself what someone answering your question would need to know before you ask a question.

Comment: @Mitch I've upgraded the question will full code.

Comment: As far as I can see, my answer is still relevant. A smaller, complete example would help. This code still won't run. All you need is two QML files, with the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should *not* do this. Using an ID of another component in a seperate QML component file is evil!

Try to avoid this at all costs. It will couple your QML components and they are not really reuseable.

So, to solve your problem you should pass the `ListView` component as a property to your `ueProductSelector` component:

```
    import QtQuick 2.5
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

    import si.mikroelektronika 1.0

    Item
    {
        id: ueProductSelector

        antialiasing: true

        clip: true

        property ListView ueUserInfoListView

        // [...]
    }
```

Then you should be able to call

```
ueOrdersModel.ueSetRecordValues(ueUserInfoListView.model.get(ueUserInfoListView.currentIndex).ueRoleId,
                                                             uePlacesListView.model.get(uePlacesListView.currentIndex).ueRoleId,
                                                             ueProductGridView.model.get(selectedIndex).ueRoleProductId,
                                                             1);
```

in your second component.

The `ListView` component is passed as a reference of (`QObject*`) and should not be performance critical.

Answer (score 2):

If the `MouseArea` was declared in `UeDelegate.qml`, and `UeListView.qml` (imaginary file names for the sake of the example) contained a `ListView` that specifies a `UeDelegate` as its `delegate`, this [would work](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html#component-instance-hierarchy). With the information you've given us, we can only assume that the `ListView` is not an ancestor of the `MouseArea`.

To elaborate on this concept:

> The component instance scope hierarchy extends to out-of-line components, too. In the following example, the TitlePage.qml component creates two TitleText instances. Even though the TitleText type is in a separate file, it still has access to the title property when it is used from within the TitlePage. QML is a dynamically scoped language - depending on where it is used, the title property may resolve differently.

```
// TitlePage.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    property string title

    TitleText {
        size: 22
        anchors.top: parent.top
    }

    TitleText {
        size: 18
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}

// TitleText.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Text {
    property int size
    text: "<b>" + title + "</b>"
    font.pixelSize: size
}
```